Django connection to Postgresql encoding problem
I can not connect Django to PostgreSQL database. It show me an encoding problem:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 86: invalid start byte

The problem is in that line:
  File "C:\Users\Robo\Desktop\Stock\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

I have tried to change encoding in Settings option, but with no results.
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "Stocks",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
        "encoding": "utf-8",

    }
}


When searching about this issue there's various different possibilities and the problem is just that psycopg2 fails to show the error properly. Either your username / password is incorrect or you've got the port for the database wrong or potentially your database is actually using something else as the encoding.

I am aware of that. All the data from my side is ok. name etc. The problem probably is with the module psycopg2 but I did not figure it out yet.

What I tried so far:
pip install psycopg2-binary,
pip install psycopg2==2.8.5 install old psycopg2 version,
pip install wheel,
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0,
pip install pillow,
install new Python version,
pip install postgresql,
install visual studio build tools,
all packages upgrade

Try using psycopg3 instead, that will probably give you a more descriptive error.

Did you create a fresh environment with a fresh install of django and psycopg2 and test it again? Are you sure you are using the correct settings module? This could lead to wrong credentials being passed to psycopg2 which, as said, then throws a misleading error.

Yes I heve just tried to create a fresh env no results. I also desactiveted antyvirus system

I have the strong feeling, that your psycopg2 package is too old. Maybe some old version got installed as a dependency for another package. Update it with: pip install --upgrade psycopg2.
The dictionary does not work with an "encoding" keyword. If you want to specify the encoding do it like this:
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "Stocks",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "options": "-c client_encoding=utf8"
        }
    }
}


Does not working

Most likely, this is an issue with Psycopg; it causes a lot of problems, especially with some 2.x releases.  Try to rollback to 2.9.9 if you have a requirements.txt, you can look for the package in there and change the version or, as suggested above by @Tarquinius, you can install it via terminal.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
